# Programmatically getting data from an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, ingress-game

First of all, I'm logged into the [Ingress Intel map](https://www.ingress.com/intel). Secondly, I'm trying to get to the data programmatically, so I put an iframe into a blank document on my server:

And I'm examining the console tab as I click on a portal. It issues a post to https://www.ingress.com/r/getPortalDetails. When I click on it in the console, it shows me lots of very interesting data like:

http://lh4.ggpht.com/gP8fhtFSO8msLyV_QLFxH6qAj1PpbcLjKh4iX3zbWSkf4w61O55wiP1nF6zUhweouivLSgl6QxXZgeRsuB9IZg

which is the picture of the portal - something that's is quite small on the intel map. What I'd like to do is parse the result.

My goal is to write a program to look at a list of guardian portal candidates and tell me which ones I need to recharge.

Q: Can I use JavaScript to programmatically interrogate a list of portals to get their current state? I think the only possible route is to use an iframe, but there might be another clever solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: Doesn't the dupe, if it is one, solve it for you?